# React navigation 5.0 header button

Tags: react-native

I trying to add right navigation header button directly on from Component, and implementation steps have been changed navigation 5.0 version, there is one method that provide add button with method

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => (
      <Button onPress={() => setCount(c => c + 1)} title="Update count" />
    ),
  });

  return <Text>Count: {count}</Text>;
}
```

but need to implement on it

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {


    constructor() {
        super()

    }
    render() {
        return ()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in your component constructor

```
this.props.navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => <Button />
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer for ReactNavigation V5

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Stack.Screen
    code..//
        options={{
        code...//
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
              title="Info"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
```